# Draw Logic Circuits with Fanout Branches using python's schemdraw/logicparser

Tags: python-3.x

I wonder if it is possible to draw a logic circuit with its fanouts drawn as well using schemdraw, e.g. f=(a and b) or a, here Net 'a' branches to both gates. Using [the docs of schemdraw](https://schemdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements/logic.html), the example circuit can be generated like this:

```
from schemdraw.parsing import logicparse
with logicparse('(a and b) or a', outlabel='$f$') as d:
  d.save('circuit.svg')
```

This code produces the following svg image:
[image]

Can I change the code somehow such that the image connects between the two nets labeled 'a'? E.g., to get something similar to the following:
[image]

Note the red wire which is a fanout branch of a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schemdraw's logicparse module isn't smart enough to do that (yet). You'd have to draw it manually, something like this:

```
with schemdraw.Drawing() as d:
    d += (a := logic.And().label('b', 'in1'))
    d += (b := logic.Or().at(a.out, dy=-.5).anchor('in1').label('f', 'out'))
    d += logic.Line().at(a.out).to(b.in1)
    d += logic.Line().at(a.in2).toy(b.in2).dot()
    d += logic.Line().at(b.in2).tox(a.in2.x-.5).label('a', 'left')
```